How to turn a circle into multiples shapes?
I have a cut a sphere and two and filled the faces at the cut. But I would like to paint those two half-sphere and for that I would need the face that I created to be on multiple pieces. Is there a way to create vertical and horizontal cuts all over this face ?

I assume you haven't actually filled the face in that image? If so, have you tried using Grid Fill by Alt-selecting the edge ring and using Face > Grid Fill in Edit mode?

Note that you do not need to make them separate meshes to have different appearances for different areas. One way you could do it is to create separate material groups on the mesh, and assign faces to which material group you want.
